# Computing every boolean function with a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_3$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, boolean-functions, arithmetic-circuits

The [following](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~arkadev/singleLayer2G.pdf) paper briefly mentions the power of $MOD_6$ gates (page 3), and relies on the unstated fact that every boolean function can be computed with an arithmetic circuit of depth 2 over $\mathbb{F}_3$. I'm not sure how this is done.

Comment: Asking about a claimed fact in a research paper is definitely grad-student level, which I think is fine for this site.

Comment: @Suresh: That is a very broad statement.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Somehow I knew you'd object to it :)

Comment: @Suresh: Honestly, I do not know why you posted that obviously incorrect claim.  In addition, I do not know what those four users who voted your comment up are thinking.  If you wanted to provoke me for some reason, you won.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every function $\mathbb{F}_p^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{F}_p$ (where $p$ is prime) can be written as a polynomial. For the proof, consider all $p^n$ monomials, and show that they are linearly independent.